# Prolog - Using sublists to produce different outcomes

Tags: prolog

As of late I have been practicing with sublists, and decided to produce an example that was pertinent to my work. This is a moderately simplified version of what I currently have, but should be just as operational for testing purposes:

```
wordsA([aaa, bbb, ccc]).
wordsB([ddd, eee, fff]).

start:-writeln('Sublist initiated'), begin.
begin:-readln(A),
maplist(downcase_atom, A, X),
X \= [quit] ->
maplist(checkAtom,X,Temp),
sort(Temp,Case),
wrt(Case),
bot;
writeln('Sublist demo').

checkAtom(A,X):-
wordsA(Y),member(A,Y)-> X = wA;
wordsB(Y),member(A,Y)-> X = wB;
caseA(Y),member(A,Y)-> X = cA;
caseB(Y),member(A,Y)-> X = cB;
caseC(Y),member(A,Y)-> X = cC;
X = nothing.

% Case determiners

caseA([finish]).
caseB([end]).
caseC([stop]).

wrt(Case):-
sublist([wA,wB,cA],Case) -> writeln('answer');
sublist([wA,wB,cB],Case) -> writeln('solution');
sublist([wA,wB,cC],Case) -> writeln('result');
writeln('Solution not found').

sublist([], _ ).
sublist([X|XS], [X|XSS] ) :- sublist( XS, XSS ).
sublist([X|XS], [_|XSS] ) :- sublist( [X|XS], XSS ).
```

Now, what I intend to happen is that one types "start" to start the loop which then asks for an input (Sublist initiated). One should then be able to type a word from the wordsA row, a word from the wordsB row and a determining case to produce one of three unique outcomes; 'answer', 'solution' and 'result' (e.g. "aaa ddd finish" - "answer")

However, what happens instead is that Prolog treats what has been typed in as an unrecognized entry and produces the fourth outcome; 'Solution not found'. I have repetitively analyzed my code time and again and have been unable to diagnose precisely what has caused the program to not recognize my input.

I am not 100% sure what has gone wrong here, and I do not believe this mistake to be a major fault, but I would like to know what has happened and what needs to be done to get my sublist to function as intended.

Comment: Say `listing` to see how your code should be indented!

Comment: Did you read the documentation regarding operator precedence? I assume you also.saw the warning about your disjoint predicate clause  definitions? If you define predicate clause `foo(A) :-...` then `bar(X) :- ...` then `foo(B) :- ...` that's a problem and `foo(B)` definition could be ignored.